# Asana API for Projects Assigned to Me

Tags: api

For Tasks assigned to me, I see how I can do

```
curl -u <api_key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace=14916&assignee=me"
```

I am trying to make a quick page that breaks down my current tasks and links to Asana for me, so I can have my own quick dashboard.

I have my API Key

- It lists all Workspaces I am a part of.
- If I click a Workspace it shows all Projects inside of that space
- If I click a Project I want to see only the Tasks that have been assigned to me inside of that Project.
- If I add the Project ID to that above call, it sends me back every item in the Project, not just those assigned to me.
- If I leave the Project ID out, it returns all tasks assigned to me, even those outside of the project.

Did I miss something?

Thanks for any help!

> ***Note:** I would add the Asana tag, but it doesn't appear to exist yet.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the current version of the API the assignee parameter is ignored when specified for projects. Regardless of what I put below, I get the same result: all tasks.

```
curl -u <api-key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/<pid>/tasks?assignee=here-it-can-be-anything"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with this too - it seems you can't expand projects when querying tasks - and you can't get tasks by project...  The former is actually preferred since you could provide a task list by project if you could expand on project.

As it is, you can get a list of tasks, then loop through and get the full task by task-id, but that takes a while...